# DynamoDB: Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I can query a GSI via DynamoDB console as can be seen in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot: the query]

When I run the same query with Boto3 on terminal with the following code:

```
table.query(
    IndexName='date-timestamp-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('date').eq('20161231'),
    FilterExpression=Attr('timestamp').between(1483130000, 1483133600) & Attr('tags').exists()
)
```

I get a `ValidationException` exception:

```
Filter Expression can only contain non-primary key attributes: Primary key attribute: timestamp
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your `timestamp` field is the sort key of the table, so it cannot be used in FilterExpression. It must be part of the KeyConditionExpression.

Comment: I thought "KeyConditionExpression" is only for the partition key. Thanks.

Comment: But what can I do to filter by timestamp? - I want to fetch all Products which have not expired yet...

Comment: @JanisBasisBasovs you can use the KeyConditionExpression to filter as you would do using the "normal filter"

Comment: then also its not possible if you want to do not equal

Comment: Love it :) You can't use "or" for KeyCondition and can't use rKey in "FilterCondition". Badummmms